# Managed Property for Site/Subsite that document lives on?

Tags: document-library, site-collection, managed-property

Is there a managed property that will contain the URL for the site or subsite that a document lives on? I want to pull all documents from a site collection and have them contain a link to the Document library that they live in, but NOT the document itself. Due to what im using, i would rather not have to parse the *Path* variable and would like to see if there is an easier solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the property im looking for. With **SPWebURL** i can pull the url of the site or subsite the document lives in.